# Differential equation Cauchy problem resolution.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I can't find my mistake in solving this problem

\begin{cases} y'(t) = y(t)/t + 2t(y(t))^2 \\  y(1) = 4 \end{cases}

I recognize this as a Bernoulli equation and thus apply the substitution $z(t) = 1/ y(t)$ this gives

\begin{cases} -z'(t) = z(t)/t + 2t \\  z(1) = 1/4 \end{cases} that is a first order linear so we have

$$z'(t)t +z(t) = -2 t^2 \implies t z(t) = -2t^3/3 + c$$ except that the solution is $y(t) = \frac{12t}{11- 8t^3}$ with $dom(y) =  ] -\infty, 11^{1/3}/ 2 [$ so I must have made some mistake.

[Here](http://www.dm.unibo.it/~dore/Analisi_2/Equazioni_ese.pdf) is the link to the exercise page.It's exercise 15 and the solution is at the end.

Could someone point it out for me?

Comment: You haven't solved for $y$ from your equation in $z$. Notice that $z = -2t^{2}/3 + C/t$ and $y(1) = 4 \implies 1/z(1) = 4 \implies z(1) = 1/4$ which will determine $C$, then some algebra will finish the job.

Comment: @Moo Yes, maybe I can add that the solution is $y(t) = \frac{12t}{11- 8t^3}$ and $dom(y) =  ] -\infty, 11^{1/3}/ 2 [$.

Comment: @Mattos Yes but that still does not add up to the solution, Here is the link to the exercise page http://www.dm.unibo.it/~dore/Analisi_2/Equazioni_ese.pdf .It's exercise 15 and the solution is at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$z(t)= -\frac{2}{3}t^2+\frac{c}{t}$$
$$y(t)=\frac{1}{-\frac{2}{3}t^2+\frac{c}{t}}=\frac{3t}{c-2t^3}$$
Since $-\infty<t<11^{1/3}/2=t_{max} \quad\to\quad c-2t_{max}^3=0 \quad\to\quad c=2t_{max}^3=2(11^{1/3}/2)^3=\frac{11}{4}$
$$y(t)=\frac{3t}{\frac{11}{4}-2t^3}=\frac{12t}{11-8t^3}$$